# I'm trying to create a numeric keypad that has a clear button and a piece on top that shows the numbers clicked on. So far I have

Tags: java, keypad

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make the clear button stretch across the entire panel. I am also having a hard time finding how to create the portion above the panel that shows the keys that the user clicks on. Please help? Here is what I have so far... I tried to change the size of the clear button but that portion of the code does nothing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TelephonePanel extends JPanel
{
    public TelephonePanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setLayout (new GridLayout (5, 3));
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300, 400));

        JButton b1 = new JButton ("1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton ("2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton ("3");
        JButton b4 = new JButton ("4");
        JButton b5 = new JButton ("5");
        JButton b6 = new JButton ("6");
        JButton b7 = new JButton ("7");
        JButton b8 = new JButton ("8");
        JButton b9 = new JButton ("9");
        JButton ba = new JButton ("*");
        JButton b0 = new JButton ("0");
        JButton bp = new JButton ("#");

        JButton bclear = new JButton ("Clear");
        bclear.setSize(new Dimension(300, 100));

        add (b1);
        add (b2);
        add (b3);
        add (b4);
        add (b5);
        add (b6);
        add (b7);
        add (b8);
        add (b9);
        add (ba);
        add (b0);
        add (bp);
        add (bclear);
    }   
}
```

Comment: use a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) instead: it allows for components to span multiple cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this, see if it is something like what you are looking for.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TelephonePanel extends JPanel {

String numberString = "";

JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
JButton ba = new JButton("*");
JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
JButton bp = new JButton("#");
JButton bclear = new JButton("Clear");

public TelephonePanel() {

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 3));

    panel1.add(b1);
    panel1.add(b2);
    panel1.add(b3);
    panel1.add(b4);
    panel1.add(b5);
    panel1.add(b6);
    panel1.add(b7);
    panel1.add(b8);
    panel1.add(b9);
    panel1.add(ba);
    panel1.add(b0);
    panel1.add(bp);

    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();

    b1.addActionListener(listener);

    // add listener to all buttons

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bclear, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(jtf, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    jtf.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 30));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(new TelephonePanel());
            frame.setSize(300, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            numberString += "1";
            jtf.setText(numberString);
        } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
            numberString += "2";
            jtf.setText(numberString);
        }

        // finish all the else ifs
    }

}
}
```

Comment: The clear button is in the right spot now, thank you so much. My teacher tends to teach us the information we need for homework (the BorderLayout.CENTER etc) the week after it is due. Do you know how I could add a bar at the top of the panel that shows the user input? I know I need action listeners on each button, I need to add those.

Comment: I believe it's called a textfield? I'm not sure.

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Works perfectly. Now I just need to do some research on the invokeLater, ActionEvent e, and new Runnable parts of the code so I can understand why this works. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Accepted, thanks again. What do I set the text to on the clear button?

Comment: `setText("");` for nothing.

Comment: Awesome. Now, all I need to do is understand. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I made a little performance fix. I added a `numberString` you can see at top of code, and what I did was add to the string so that when mukltiple buttons are pressed, the text will be added continuously. So you should also make that fix.